# Googe Maps: Cannot read property 'setDirections' of undefined

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, google-api, vuejs2, directions

I'm a beginner on using Google Maps API and I just want some help with regards with my error below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDirections' of undefined
at eval (google-maps.vue?1cba:101)
at directions.js:8
at gm.j (directions.js:5)
at Object.c [as _3lwmum] (common.js:46)
at VM1924 DirectionsService.Route:1
```

Here's my code that implements the Directions API

```
getRoute() {
  this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService()
  this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer()
  this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.$refs.googleMap.$mapObject)
  this.directionsService.route({
    origin: this.location.position,
    destination: { lat: 62, lng: 15 },
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function (response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      this.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response)
    } else {
      console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status)
    }
  })
},
```

And this is what the 'this.$refs.googleMap.$mapObject' value looks like

[image: this.$refs.googleMap.$mapObject value]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this` refers to the function in callback since you are not using arrow function for that, there are a 2 approaches for that

1. Assign the `this` to a variable before using the function with callback:

   `getRoute() {
      this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService()
      this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer()
      this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.$refs.googleMap.$mapObject)
      const _self = this
      this.directionsService.route({
        origin: this.location.position,
        destination: { lat: 62, lng: 15 },
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      }, function (response, status) {
         if (status === 'OK') {
           _self.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response)
         } else {
           console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status)
         }
       })`
2. Use arrow function for the callback

   `getRoute() {
       this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService()
       this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer()
       this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.$refs.googleMap.$mapObject)
       this.directionsService.route({
        origin: this.location.position,
        destination: { lat: 62, lng: 15 },
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
      }, (response, status) => {
         if (status === 'OK') {
           this.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response)
         } else {
           console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status)
         }
       })`

Answer (score 1):

`this` in function callback is different. It's not Vue instance.

You can use this trick:

```
getRoute() {
  this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService()
  this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer()
  this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.$refs.googleMap.$mapObject)
  var self = this
  this.directionsService.route({
    origin: this.location.position,
    destination: { lat: 62, lng: 15 },
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function (response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      self.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response)
    } else {
      console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status)
    }
  })
```